# save_post hook - headers already sent?

Tags: functions, hooks, headers, pluggable

I'm trying to create a very simple alert for each time a post is created or updated with the below...

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'updatedAlert' );
function updatedAlert() {
  echo '<script>alert("post updated!");</script>';
}
```

The moment I drop this in I get "headers already sent" in both post.php and pluggable.php.

Am I missing something obvious? It seems like there shouldn't be anything else to it!

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a popup to confirm to the user that the post they have edited or updated has been saved as some users are missing it. I was hoping if I could just tap into the save_post hook then it would be a quick way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Saving post doesn't *just* happens. Either you are submitting a form or ajax request, which spins up new copy of WP core, which does the saving. Typically that process isn't *meant* to produce output and isn't handling it accordingly.

Depending on what you want to accomplish you will have to either use pure JavaScript for solution or store the message during saving persistently and output it at more appropriate point in the process.

Comment: Thank you for this. What I'm trying to achieve is a popup to confirm to the user that the post they have edited or updated has been saved as some users are missing it. I was hoping if I could just tap into the save_post hook then it would be a quick way to do it!